# FieldSet CSS Styles not working on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css

```css
fieldset.scheduler-border {
    border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #ccc;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

fieldset.scheduler-border:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px transparent;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="text-center">
<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border">Contenido de la incidencia</legend>
    <div class="radio radio-inline radio-primary">
         <input type="radio" name="nQueEs" id="idQueEsQueja" value="queja" defaultChecked/>
         <label for="idQueEsQueja">Queja</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I have next CSS:

```
fieldset.scheduler-border {
    border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #ccc;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

fieldset.scheduler-border:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px transparent;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border">Contenido de la incidencia</legend>
    /*MY FORM*/
</fieldset>
```

It is working perfect on Google Chrome, but not in Mozilla Firefox. How could I resolve it? Thank you.

EDIT: I added an Snnipet, it is first time I do, I hope it is well. Thank you.

Comment: Can you include your HTML? Better still, add a snippet (The `<>` icon in the edit tool bar)

Comment: Ok I will try. Never used it

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: I’m running Firefox on my Mac, and it appears to be working. What were you looking for? What version of Firefox, and what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10. on FireFox 53.0.2 (32-bit

Comment: @JuMoGar ok try my answer in your Firefox. If it is not working, which part? shadow?

Comment: `<fieldset>` seems to be the problem here. If you replace it with a `<div>` it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. If I replace with a Div do not see as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your Firefox maybe?
Firefox fieldset legend have a bug for a long time, a workaround could be set a margin top for `legend` and reduce that margin for `fieldset`.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  fieldset {
    margin-top: -0.9em;
  }
  legend.scheduler-border {
    margin-top: 0.9em;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 6.5em);
  }
}
```

I updated your css with:

```
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #ccc;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #ccc;
  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #ccc;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  /* Android 2.1+, Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6  */
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+  */
```

```css
fieldset.scheduler-border {
  border: 1px groove #ddd;
  padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #ccc;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #ccc;
  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #ccc;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  /* Android 2.1+, Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6  */
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+  */
}

fieldset.scheduler-border:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px transparent
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px transparent;
  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px transparent;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  /* Android 2.1+, Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6  */
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+  */
}

legend.scheduler-border {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  fieldset {
    margin-top: -0.9em;
  }
  legend.scheduler-border {
    margin-top: 0.9em;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 6.5em);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="text-center">
  <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border">Contenido de la incidencia</legend>
    <div class="radio radio-inline radio-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="nQueEs" id="idQueEsQueja" value="queja" defaultChecked/>
      <label for="idQueEsQueja">Queja</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But continue not working. Shadow works fine. Legend is above the edge of Fieldset, also in Chrome I appear centered (Legend) and in FireFox aligned to the left. Those are the two main differences.

Comment: @JuMoGar ok I see what is your problem.

Comment: And do you know why could it be?

Comment: @JuMoGar it is a bug for 8 years for firefox, check my updated code for a workaround?

Comment: Thank you! Legend is now aligned with Fieldset!!. But now ... In your Snippet it aligns to the center correctly, but nevertheless in my page no ... And I have copied your code as if in case it was changing something bad in mine, is very rare

Comment: @JuMoGar I removed all !important, try this time?

Comment: I copied this new code but it continues without being aligned to the center

Comment: @JuMoGar ok try this now. I used margin-left to move the legend to center (not perfect center unless you know the width of that lengend, but if this work you can improve it later)

Comment: Yes! At least it is an interim solution ... Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @JuMoGar happy to help